# Why has_term does not work with AND operator?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with multiple conditional in WooCommerce doing specific actions according to the existing categories in the cart:

```
if( (has_term( 'prestamos-empresa', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ))) && (has_term( 'productos-de-ahorro', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ))) ){            
               unset($fields['billing']['info_financiera']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_iban']); 
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_titularcuenta']); 
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_sinmoroso']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_cargorol']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_ingreso']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_tipocontrato']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_antiguedad']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_fechasueldo']);
            }
```

If I use OR operator if it works, also try && and nothing. I will leave another piece of my code:

```
    function campos_checkout_condicional( $fields ){        

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {        
        $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );        

            // Si esta Micro Prestamos o Prestamos Personales en carrito devolver todos los campos.
            if( has_term( array('micro-prestamos','prestamos-personales'), 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ) ) ){
                return $fields;
            }

            // Solo prestamos empresas y productos de ahorro en carrito.
            if( (has_term( 'prestamos-empresa', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ))) && (has_term( 'productos-de-ahorro', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ))) ){            
               unset($fields['billing']['info_financiera']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_iban']); 
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_titularcuenta']); 
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_sinmoroso']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_cargorol']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_ingreso']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_tipocontrato']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_antiguedad']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_fechasueldo']);
            }

            // Solo prestamos empresa e inversion // Solo productos de ahorro y inversion
            if( ((has_term( 'prestamos-empresa', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ))) && (has_term( 'inversion', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id )))) || ((has_term( 'productos-de-ahorro', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id ))) && (has_term( 'inversion', 'product_cat', get_post( $product_id )))) ){            
               unset($fields['billing']['info_financiera']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_iban']); 
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_titularcuenta']); 
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_sinmoroso']);
               unset($fields['billing']['billing_fechasueldo']);
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Implement the complete function, use && and it does not work as desired. For example: I want that if there are only two specific categories do such action (if category1 && category2) ...

How could it work? And why does not it work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&`  instead of `AND` boolean operator.

Use `||`  instead of `OR` boolean operator.

Comment: I have updated the post, using that does not work. I have made sure that the categories are present in the cart, and if I use || if it works but it does not fulfill what I want.

Comment: they way i read your code, boolean operator is not the issue.
I think it's the way you use your functions if returning the a proper BOOLEAN or 1 or 0  or NULL return.

Comment: Could you explain a little more please?

Comment: please read:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php   with dealing with BOOLEAN and logic, it's kinda bit a tricky business. You have to anticipate the results which holds TRUE or FALSE.